# Replace Logo Image with Text in website header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replace the image area for my logo with "text" so that I can have the logo display as "text" instead of an uploaded image.

I have tested in in the inspector in Chrome, and it looks fantastic !

I added this:   inside the "elt-position-center-inner" (inside the inspector in chrome - along with the below css, and it is perfect.

I know where to place the css - I just don't know where to add this "div" in the page templates? I cannot find these other "divs" around it any any of the php code of the pages ?

```
<div class="logo_text">
<p>dearDOMINIQUE</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo_text {
    font-family: "Playfair Display",serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: black;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open your active theme header.php file and find div class in this file and where you can replace this thing.

**also You can upload your logo image in admin side follow below step**

1. Appearance -> Customize

in customize in your need to find header logo upload option.

Comment: Unfortunately these "div" containers do not reflect in my header.php ?

Comment: I would like to use text, instead of an image for the logo

Answer (score 0):

I located the required php files within the theme folder:
/framework/modules/header/templates/parts/logo.php